# problem in asp.net webform using radio button html in reapeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radio-button, asprepeater

When I use radio button html without using repeater, there is no problem and it works properly, but when I use repeater, jQuery functions do not work.
Thank you for your help

Styles and JS Link

```
        <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #222;
    }

    .custom-radios div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label {
      color: #333;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 44px;
    }

    .custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label{
      display: flexbox;
      color: #FFFFFF;

    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span img {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all .3s ease;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-1 + label span {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-2 + label span {
      background-color: #3498db;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-3 + label span {
      background-color: #f1c40f;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-4 + label span {
      background-color: #e74c3c;
    }
    .custom-radios input[type="radio"]:checked + label span img {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Controls/Form

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <span id="submittername" style="color: #FFFFFF"></span>
            <br />


            <div class="custom-radios">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <div>
                            <span style="color: #ffffff;display:grid;position: relative;left:10px; bottom: 10px;"><%# Eval("ColorName") %></span>
                            <input type="radio" id="<%# Eval("ColorID") %>" name="color" value="<%# Eval("ColorName") %>">
                            <label for="color-1">
                              <span>
                                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
                              </span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
  

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
  


              <div>

                  <span style="color: #ffffff;display:grid;position: relative;left:10px; bottom: 10px;">blue</span>
                    <input type="radio" id="color-2" name="color" value="blue">
                    <label for="color-2">
                      <span>
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
                      </span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
  
              <div>
                  <span style="color: #ffffff;display:grid;position: relative;left:10px; bottom: 10px;">yellow</span>
                    <input type="radio" id="color-3" name="color" value="yellow">
                    <label for="color-3">
                      <span>
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
                      </span>
                    </label>
                  </div>

              <div>
                  <span style="color: #ffffff;display:grid;position: relative;left:10px; bottom: 10px;">red</span>
                    <input type="radio" id="color-4" name="color" value="red">
                    <label for="color-4">
                      <span>
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
                      </span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input:radio[name=color]:first").attr('checked', true);
            var selValue = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            $("#submittername").text(selValue);
            //console.log(selValue);
        });
        $(".custom-radios").click(function () {
            var selValue = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            $("#submittername").text(selValue);
            //console.log(selValue);
        });
      </script>
```

Simple code works without repeater.

In repeater there are 3 colors that document.ready correctly, but when click does not work.
Below that are simple codes that work properly without repeater.
The problem is using the repeater with jQuery.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to show the product color scheme to the user on the product specifications page and the user can choose the desired color. Colors must be read from the database and I need repeater. When the page loads, the first item is checked, but when clicking on other colors, the operation is not performed correctly. But when the colors are placed manually without using repeater, the click operation and selecting other colors is quite successful.

Comment: The first 3 colors, which include the circles on the left, are read from the database and are not clickable, but the three colors on the right are out of repeater and are set in batches that work properly.
The problem is that when you put radio button in html format inside repeater, the clicking operation does not work or is not done properly.   i put two pics in answer...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the 3 left circles being empty because their color code is not defined on the page. The problem is that by clicking on the 3 circles created with repeater , nothing happens, but the 3 circles on the right that have been added manually work properly.

Comment: Whats the result of the `id="<%# Eval("ColorID") %>"` Expression?

Comment: I found my problem : in <label for="color-1"> i must change it to <label for="<%# Eval("ColorID") %>">.   hooray

Comment: ColorID is unique id for colors. i inter same ColorID in label for element and fixed.

Comment: that's exactly it :)
but your styles will not work anymore: `.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-1` will not match anything.

Comment: Thanks Homungus for following up

Comment: yes.  I am now editing my css code according to the database